# Could not install stable-diffusion-webui (StabilityMatrix.Core.Exceptions.ProcessException: Venv creation failed with code 1

Tags: python, python-venv

Could somebody help me...
Trying to install Stable Diffusion WebUI from StablityMatrix, but this error "Package Modification Failed" comes out. I could install and use ComfyUI.

Error code:

```
Unpacking resources
Unpacking resources
Download Complete
C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\0ec8c814-55da-41a5-b69d-fa251c113653_StabilityMatrix-win-x64.zip.653\Data\Assets\Python310\python.exe: No module named virtualenv

Could not install stable-diffusion-webui (StabilityMatrix.Core.Exceptions.ProcessException: Venv creation failed with code 1
   at StabilityMatrix.Core.Python.PyVenvRunner.Setup(Boolean existsOk, Action`1 onConsoleOutput, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at StabilityMatrix.Core.Models.Packages.A3WebUI.InstallPackage(String installLocation, TorchVersion torchVersion, SharedFolderMethod selectedSharedFolderMethod, DownloadPackageVersionOptions versionOptions, IProgress`1 progress, Action`1 onConsoleOutput)
   at StabilityMatrix.Core.Models.Packages.A3WebUI.InstallPackage(String installLocation, TorchVersion torchVersion, SharedFolderMethod selectedSharedFolderMethod, DownloadPackageVersionOptions versionOptions, IProgress`1 progress, Action`1 onConsoleOutput)
   at StabilityMatrix.Core.Models.PackageModification.InstallPackageStep.ExecuteAsync(IProgress`1 progress)
   at StabilityMatrix.Core.Models.PackageModification.PackageModificationRunner.ExecuteSteps(IReadOnlyList`1 steps))
```

[image]
[Stable Diffusion WebUI Folder]
[image]
[Stable Diffusion WebUI Folder / venv]
[image]

- OS: Windows 10
- Python(stability matrix): 3.10.11
- Stability matrix version: 2.9.0